# Stability of a degenerate equilibrium in a planer ODE using center manifold approach

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I have a planer ODE system which is given by
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{array}{lll}\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt} = p_{20}x^2+p_{11}xy+p_{30}x^3+p_{21}x^2y+p_{40}x^4+p_{31}x^3y+p_{22}x^2y^2,\\
\frac{dy}{dt} =-my+q_{11}xy+q_{21}x^2y+q_{31}x^3y,
 \end{cases}\end{array}
 \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}
with $m,p_{20},p_{40},p_{22}$ and $q_{11}$ are all positive; $p_{11},p_{30}$ and $q_{21}$ are all negative; and the other coefficients $p_{21},p_{31}$ and $q_{31}$ can be any values. Clearly, the above system have an equilibrium point $E_0=(0,0)$.
I have to find the stability (or, instability) properties of $E_0=(0,0)$ of the system $(1)$.

Now, using linearized stability analysis, the Jacobian matrix is given by
$$J_{E_0}=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0\\ 0 &-m
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Clearly, the eigenvalues of $J_{E_0}$ are $0$ and $-m$. So, the linearized stability analysis fails to give the local stability properties of $E_0=(0,0)$.

Now, we will move towards the  *center manifold theory* to conclude the stability properties of $E_0$.
According to the Theorem $18.1.2$  given in [Wiggins dynamical system book, page-246](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258629276_Introduction_To_Applied_Nonlinear_Dynamical_Systems_And_Chaos), there exists a center manifold for $(1)$ which can be locally represented as
$$W^c(0) =\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|~~y=h(x), |x|<\delta, h(0)=Dh(0)=0\},$$

where $D$ denotes the derivative and  $\delta$ is sufficiently small. Then we consider $h(x)$ as
\begin{equation}
h(x) = ax^2 + bx^3 +cx^4+ O(x^5).\tag{2}
\end{equation}
According to $(18.1.10)$ from Wiggins same book, page-248, the equation for the center manifold is given by
\begin{equation}\mathcal{N}(h(x))=Dh(x)[Ax+f(x,h(x))]-Bh(x)-g(x,h(x))=0,\tag{3}
\end{equation}
where $A=0$, $B=-m$, $f(x,y)=p_{20}x^2+p_{11}xy+p_{30}x^3+p_{21}x^2y+p_{40}x^4+p_{31}x^3y+p_{22}x^2y^2$, and $g(x,y)=q_{11}xy+q_{21}x^2y+q_{31}x^3y$.

Now we obtain the value $a$, $b$ and $c$ in $(2)$, by calculating the coefficient of $x^i$ in $(3)$.
**Coefficient of $x^i$:**
$\qquad x^2:\quad ma=0\implies a=0$
$\qquad x^3:\quad 2p_{20}a+mb-q_{11}a=0\implies b=0$
$\qquad x^4:\quad 2p_{11}a^2+3p_{20}b+mc-q_{21}a=0\implies c=0$
$\qquad\vdots$
So, $h(x)=0$. Thus the function which determines the center manifold becomes zero. Here, I am stuck.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Also is there any other method/approach available for the stability of $E_0$?

Comment: But $y = h(x) \equiv 0$ still *is* a graph over $x$ axis. It just happens that your center manifold coincides with $Ox$, which is indeed an invariant manifold: the vector field defined by your system is tangent to it. Plug any point $(x^\ast, 0)$, you will get a tangent vector $(*, \; 0)$ which is tangent to $y = 0$. The only caveat is that a center manifold is not always a unique thing, but the dynamics on all center manifolds is topologically the same as far as I remember. So it is suffice to study what happens at $y = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Follows a MATHEMATICA script which calculates the leaves of the center manifold. The script is self explanatory. We can see that in this case we have one leave, being  the $x$ axis.

```
n = 6;
f[x_, y_] := p20 x^2 + p11 x y + p30 x^3 + p21 x^2 y + p40 x^4 + p31 x^3 y + p22 x^2 y^2
g[x_, y_] := q11 x y + q21 x^2 y + q31 x^3 y
h[x_] := Sum[a[k] x^k, {k, 2, n}]
A = Table[a[k], {k, 2, n}];
dif = D[h[x], x] f[x, h[x]] - g[x, h[x]];
coefs = Take[CoefficientList[dif, x], {4, n + 2}];
sol = Solve[coefs == 0, A]
```

Comment: In MATHEMATICA,  we have also one leave, which is the x-axis. Since h(0)=Dh(0)=0 so in your MATHEMATICA scripts h[x_] := Sum[a[k] x^k, {k, 2, n}]. Also dif = D[h[x], x] f[x, h[x]] + mh[x] - g[x, h[x]]. Thus two leaves arise for these two typing errors.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Now it is fixed. One leave.